# CSS:hover remaining when an element is moved from the cursor in Chrome - Is there a workaround?

Tags: css

I'm working with an app interface, currently developing in Chrome, and I don't have time today to isolate this issue explicitly in an example here (I will try to add it as an edit), but it seems (at least under certain conditions, perhaps always) when an element is given a `:hover` CSS style, and then the item is moved away from the cursor, the `:hover` CSS styles remain until I move the mouse.

In this case, I have a list of items (divs) and I'm pinching (setting the height to 0, with a 0.3s transition applied to height change) all items except one, so that one rises to the top to become the header for a new menu. And even as it rises to the top of the list, it keeps its `:hover` CSS styles.

I'm wondering if this is a know Chrome bug, and if so, if there is a workaround I can apply to patch this behavior. *If it isn't a known problem, I'll try to edit this with an isolated example of the issue.*

Comment: you need to add styling for  `:focus` as well, its the state after `:active` like - normal > hover > active > focus

Comment: @Deepak I thought focus was only applied to inputs when selected (and the page when the tab is open, iirc).

Comment: Its also applicable for buttons, anchor tag, `a:focus`

Comment: If you do a quick code dump that recreates it, as isolated as possible, it will be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn {background:tomato;border:0;padding:8px 26px;color:#fff;}

.btn:hover {background:blue;}
.btn:focus {background:green;} /* when pressed mouse key is removed */
.btn:active {background:#303030;} /* when mouse key is in pressed state */

Example
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: This looks about right, you could explain it a tiny bit more outside the snippet.